# Loop problems in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have two problems both with loops.

First question, is it possible to make loop(while or something else) that would wait my command.

For example, I need to choose a possible move and until I have chance for next move I must have chance to choose.

```
While(eat==1){
  if(CGRectContainsPoint([BOX9 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])){
   eat=0;
  }
}
```

My problem is that while spinning in circle and BOX9 can't be pressed because  spinning and spinning. I need some loop that spin circle but will allow selection of next command. I hope I was clear, English is not my strong point.

---

Second problem

Second problem is with while loop. On touch I show image from UIimageView controller to another. Sometimes I have more movements, and I need use while because i never know how movements I wold have. And I would like to make this movements slower.

If i write in code that i want `uiimage1.image=someimage;` that work fine. But problem is when I say for example:

```
uiimage1.image=someimage; 
while(eat==1){
uiimage2.image=uiimage1.image;
uiimage1.image=NULL;
uiimage3.image=uiimage1.image;
}
```

(This is only example code,that I wrote now,to better explain problem.)

If i making some waiting inside "while loop", always I getting that slower show is of only first image,second two changes are fast.

I try with transition effect to make slower, but that works only when I load some picture in imagecontroller with touch. If i wrote in code, transition wont work.

All is in `touchesBegin` function.

Thank's for help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you write, but the answer is NO. You can't wait if while loop. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I need make some games for college, similar to chess but after one eat of opposite figure, i can eat more, until i not have chance for that. 
And while loop is for checking my chances and not change player until i make move and eat all what i can. I don't know how figure i wold eat, and i eat it on touch. I don't know how better to explain. While is until i have chance for next eating, and inside of loop are possible uiimage controllers in witch i can move my figure when i eat somebody. i hope that this was clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from what I can tell, you are making a game, and want to animate things. Your problem is that your while loops are on the main thread, so until they finish no user input is accepted and the screen doesn't refresh.

There are several ways to solve this, all of which involve moving the execution of things that happen in "real-time," by which I mean things that are presented to the user, off of the main thread.

The first: You make an `NSTimer` with `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`. Your selector handles the animation of things in "real time". When `touchesBegan` is called, you set the flag `eating`. This looks roughly like this in code

```
-(void) setUp

{

       NSTimer scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 
                                      target: self 
                                    selector: @selector(runLoop) 
                                    userInfo: NULL 
                                     repeats: YES];
}

-(void) runLoop
{
    if(eatingDuration && eating)
    {

        eatingDuration--;
        //do something because we're eating
     }         

}

 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
      //if we need to set eating to yes do it

             eating = YES;
             eatingDuration = whatEverWeNeedItToBe;
 }
```

This might be thought of as a "run loop," because it is called repeatedly until you get rid of the timer. It is probably the best method to do this.

The second: You use the `animateWithDuration:animations:` class method of UIView to animate each individual element.

Comment: Yes, I think that I am understand all, and that wold help me, I wold try to implement in code, Thank You very much.